# Combine two sort conditions one ascending the other descending

Tags: python, sorting

I would like to combine two sort conditions but one is ascending the other descending.

The input data are this list of tuples:

```
data = [
    ('Apple', 4),
    ('Cherry', 5),
    ('Ananas', 4),
    ('Blueberry', 3),
    ('Banana', 3)
]
```

The sorting conditions:

1. 2nd tuple item (the `int`) in *reverse* order.
2. "Inside" that sub groups: 1rst tuple item (the `str`) in regular lexicographic order.

The expected result should be

```
    ('Cherry', 5),
    ('Ananas', 4),
    ('Apple', 4),
    ('Banana', 3),
    ('Blueberry', 3),
```

I know that I can combine conditions like this:

```
sort(data, key=lambda x: condA(x[0]), condB(x[1]))
```

But my problem is that I don't know how to make one reverse the other not and how to do the lexicographic ordering in a lambda.

This is the MWE

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
data = [
    ('Apple', 4),
    ('Cherry', 5),
    ('Ananas', 4),
    ('Blueberry', 3),
    ('Banana', 3)
]

expect = [
    ('Cherry', 5),
    ('Ananas', 4),
    ('Apple', 4),
    ('Banana', 3),
    ('Blueberry', 3),
]

result = sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
print(result)
# [('Cherry', 5), ('Apple', 4), ('Ananas', 4), ('Blueberry', 3), ('Banana', 3)]

result = sorted(data, key=lambda x: x[0])
print(result)
# [('Ananas', 4), ('Apple', 4), ('Banana', 3), ('Blueberry', 3), ('Cherry', 5)]

# What I want.
print(expect)
# [('Cherry', 5), ('Ananas', 4), ('Apple', 4), ('Banana', 3), ('Blueberry', 3)]
```

Comment: Since `.sort()` is *stable*, you don't HAVE to handle all the sort criteria at one time.  You have the option of sorting by them individually, in increasing order of importance; this way, you can apply `reverse=True` or not to each individual sort.

Comment: I don't understand your comment. Vote for re-open because my question and MWE is of higher quality then the older one. Clearer and easier to understand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work.

```
output = sorted(data, key=lambda x: (-x[1], x[0]))
```